# sql query does not give results

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing some issue with the following query.

```
for (String string : projects) {
            String sql = "SELECT  eff.id,eff.taskNo,eff.projectId,sum(eff.hours),eff.employeeId FROM EffortCalculator eff where eff.projectId='"
                    + string + "' and  eff.dayDate >= '2014-12-15' and eff.dayDate <= '2014-12-16' GROUP BY eff.projectId";
            System.out.println("sql" + sql);
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            System.out.println(query.list());

            // query.addEntity(EffortCalculator.class);
            list.addAll(query.list());
        }
```

When I execute this query in MySQL DB it works fine. It actually contains two rows. But when I use this query in hibernate it gives empty list.

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: is `System.out.println(query.list());` printing null?

Comment: Do other queries work? If not,it could be a configuration problem.

Comment: please show how is `list` declared

Comment: I am not getting any exception.. It prints query.list().size = 0.Other queries work. when I add the date conditon it does not properly work. But it works fine in MYSQL DB

Comment: Is your "EffortCalculator" class has a mapping in the hbm.xml file with the table?

Comment: @SridharDD. Yes. I have mapped. I can save the entity.

Comment: is the DB which configured in Hibernate datasource the same as you queried manually?

Comment: can you change date format to MM-dd-yyyy and check? and use `between` sql function instead of <= and >=

Comment: I tried both.. not working.. is there any way to acheive the same output by using criteria?

Comment: did you try Query query = session.createQuery(sql); ?